# Jquery clone and append to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone tell me how do you clone from a span element and append to input value by clicking the span element itself? 
Here is the script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("span#username").click(function() {
        $("span#username").clone().appendTo("#test");


      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <span id="username"> User </span><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="test" value="" />


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the value of the input ([**jQuery.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)) to the text content of the span ([**jQuery.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)) like this:

```
// IDs are enough
$("#username").click(function() {
    $("#test").val($(this).text()); // this is the span beign clicked
});
```

**No jQuery:**

```
document.getElementById("username").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("test").value = this.textContent;
});
```

Comment: @Neof I added the code with no jQuery, just vanilla JS!